# Why would jquery not pollute global namespace?

Tags: javascript, jquery

It is said here:

http://briancrescimanno.com/2009/09/24/how-self-executing-anonymous-functions-work/

> Take a look at the source code of jQuery and you’ll see that the
>   whole library is wrapped in a single, self-executing function that is
>   assigned to the jQuery global object.

But since jQuery is GLOBAL object it does pollute global namespace or I miss something ?

Comment: Define "pollute". Does a *single object* "pollute" the namespace?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Having only one(two) variables in a global scope is not considered as pollution of the global scope. it's like a namespace, it's highly unlikely that other libraries will call their namespaces 'jQuery' (and more likely `$`). and even in that situations jQuery handles it gracefully by implementing `noConflict` function.

Comment: Oh it's very likely that other libraries will use `$`. It's a JavaScript library magnet :P

Answer (score 5):

You didn't read the next sentence in that blog post properly. It didn't claim that there is *no* pollution:

> It’s precisely the reason that jQuery doesn’t pollute the global namespace nearly as much as other libraries.

Answer (score 0):

It's also instructive to think of the alternative: if there is no object in the global scope, where is the object? Everything in Javascript has a scope, so if $ were not in the global namespace, or in another javascript object, it is unbound and inaccessible. That situation should be impossible. Every object has to go *somewhere*.

If a javascript object exists, but has no scope, is it useable?
If a tree falls in the forest, but no one is around, does it make a sound?